# how to find number of maximum

Tags: real-analysis

> Define $a_n=\frac{1000^n}{n!}$.Then $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$
>
> **(1)** does not have a maximum
>
> **(2)** attains maximum at exactly two values of $n$
>
> **(3)** attains maximum at exactly one value of $n$
>
> **(4)** attains maximum for infinitely many values of $n$

Trial: I take $\log$ and try to proceed.But I am stuck.Any help will be very helpful.Please help.

Comment: Hint: examine $a_{n+1}/a_n$.

Comment: David's hint is a good one. Here's an alternative: replace that $1000$ with something more manageable, like $4$, and write out the numbers $4^n/n!$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ until you see what's happening with regard to maxima. You may even see why it happens, but, if not, replace the $4$ with $5$, and try again --- after you've done enough of these, you will surely see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =\frac{1000^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{1000^n} =\frac{1000}{n+1}$$
 Now $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1$ for $n < 999$ again $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$ for $n = 999$ and  $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$ for $n > 999$
 So we get 
 $$a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \cdots < a _{998} < a_{999} = a_{1000} > a_{1001} > \cdots$$ 
Clearly your option $(2)$ is correct.

Comment: Not leaving much work for OP to do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : David's hint is enough. I add the arrangement of $a_n$ so that OP can check his solution or give a better representation of his solution.

Comment: I see no evidence that OP has a solution to check.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I post this answer because I think it may be helpful to OP. I am a student not a teacher so I may be wrong.

Comment: As you are a student, do you prefer to work things out on your own, or do you prefer for someone else to do all your work for you? I'm guessing you prefer the satisfaction of working things out on your own. If so, then consider that A.D may also be a student, and may wish the joy of working things out, instead of seeing it all done by someone else.